# not able to run pyspark from cmd form spark directory

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed spark 1.6(pre built for hadoop 2.6) version in my windows 10 system and I have set up the environmental variables properly. When I to run pyspark I get this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qvUP.png).

However I can run "python" command from spark directory and its returning correct version.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Why did you try spark on windows and why on earth did you download Spark 1.6 when the latest version 2.2.? If you want to just try and experiment, there are other ways like a databricks free cluster on cloud

Answer (score 2):

When you run python it directly enter into python command-line but for pyspark you have to execute pyspark executable file which is not present in this location. You are trying into  `C:\spark` but pyspark file present into this location  `C:\spark\bin\pyspark` so you need to go on this location and try to run pyspark.